# Display one day with d3.slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have my map where I display some incidents over time. Until now I used the data which is filtered like this

```
dpG = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;
dpS = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var minDate = dpG("01.01.2015");
var maxDate = dpG("31.12.2015");
var secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
  .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
  .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
    newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
var date = (dpG(d.properties.date).getTime() === new Date(value).getTime());
      // console.log(date)
      //console.log(new Date(value));

      console.log(dpG(d.properties.date));
      return(date);
    });
    // newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
    //   return dpS(d.properties.Date) < new Date(value);
    // });
    // console.log(newDataG);
        // console.log("New set size ", newDataG.length);

    displaySitesG(newDataG);
    // displaySitesS(newDataS);
  })
);
```

But now I tried to filter for only one day and not for all days until `new Date(value)`
So I tried something like this

```
newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
  var date = dpG(d.properties.date) == new Date(value);
  // console.log(date)
  //console.log(new Date(value));
  return(date);
});
```

Which turned out to be not working at all.

And something like this displays all data at once.

```
var date = new Date(value);
```

The other files is [github repo](https://github.com/RitterLean/Timeline_world) if you need to see

EDIT2:

```
date1 = Math.round(dpG(d.properties.date).getTime() / (1000*60*60*24));
date2 = Math.round(new Date(value).getTime() / (1000*60*60*24));
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2)
```

gives me this
[image: log1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used moment.js to make the UnixTimeStamp even

here is the code snippet which helped

```
d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
.axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
.on("slide", function(evt, value) {
  sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){

    //sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    dataDate = d.properties.Date;
    //dataDateStampS = moment(dataDate).unix();

    if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
      return dpS(dataDate);
    }
  });
  displaySitesS(newDataS);
})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for equality directly doesn't work with `date` objects:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(d1);
console.log(d1 == d2);   // false!
```

Instead, you need to use th `date.getTime()` operator if you want to use the `==`, `!=`, `===`, and `!==` operators:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(d1);
d1.getTime() === d2.getTime(); // true
```

So, try this instead: (**edited to fix error**)

```
var date = (dpG(d.properties.date).getTime() === new Date(value).getTime());
```

Note that this will only work if `dpG(thing)` returns a `Date` object.

Comment: I followed your tip but I get this error message `Uncaught TypeError: d.properties.date.getTime is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion should have said `dpG(d.properties.date).getTime() `. See edited answer.

Comment: I double checked and if I log the ` dpG(d.properties.date) ` I get a Date Object. But when I log date I get ` false ` only. I added some more code above

Comment: One possibility is that you are not getting an equality because `getTime()` gives you time in milliseconds. You can try to round your time to the nearest second (or minute?) by dividing by 1000 (or 1000 * 60 if minutes) and see if that works. That is `Math.round( ... .getTime() / 1000)`. Also, what is the format of `value`? If it's in the form `"DD.MM.YYYY"`, then it might make more sense to just do a string comparison.

Comment: `var date = (Math.round(dpG(d.properties.date).getTime() / (1000*60*60)) === Math.round(new Date(value).getTime() / (1000*60*60))); ` still false

Comment: and logging value gives me something like this `1421709168000`

Comment: And when you `console.log` the `date` and the `value`, are they actually equal?

Comment: no. indeed they are not equal. See Edit 2 for more information please.

Comment: if `a` and `b` are not equal, then `a == b` will return `false`, which is exactly what you are seeing. Your filter function is working exactly as it should by returning a `false` when the two date values are not equal.

Comment: Is it then possible to only get the day-month-year without the clock values or restting them because `value` has always somethign different than 00:00:00 ?